# Firebase dynamic link does not go smooth

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to use Firebase dynamic link option and succeeded to create a link that opens the app, but the opening process doesn't look smooth. It looks something like that -

1. Once I click on the link, it looks like the browser (Chrome) is opening (for a short time)
2. Then it returns to the screen from which I opened the link (in the case WhatsApp), and displays a white rectangle with a "loading" sign inside it, in the center of the screen.
3. Open the App.

This is not the case, say, if I try to access another application on my phone via a link (say Spotify or Facebook - in this case, I can see only a black screen until the app opens).

How can I get the same effect as in Spotify (a black screen)?

The part in the MANIFAST that relate to this activity -

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="thisapp.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

What else can help?